# Multiple collections with derived classes in parent entity do not work when Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) mapping strategy is used by EF6

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy, tph

I have spent better part of the weekend trying to figure this one out.

I have an existing database with Subscription table that I want to map to entities in my domain using TPH inheritance strategy.

There are several types of Subscription, and each has its own peculiarities hence the need for inheritance. Here is dumbed-down version of the domain:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class BookSubscription:Subscription
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
}
public class TVSubscription : Subscription
{
    public string Channel { get; set; }
}
```

These entities are mapped in the context as follows:

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
public DbSet<TVSubscription> TVSubscriptions { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("tblCustomer");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>()
            .Map<Subscription>(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("tblSubscription");
                m.Requires("ServiceTypeId").HasValue(1);
            })
             .Map<TVSubscription>(m =>
             {
                 m.Requires("ServiceTypeId").HasValue(20);
             })
            .Map<BookSubscription>(m =>
            {
                m.Requires("ServiceTypeId").HasValue(5);
            }
            );
    modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>().HasKey(s => s.SubscriptionID);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

As expected, when context is queried for any of the derived classes, EF correctly constructs query using ServiceTypeId as discriminator. The problem arises when I try to include derived classes in the Customer entity. This works:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions{ get; set; }      
}
```

This does not work:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TVSubscription> TvSubscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Neither does this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TVSubscription> TvSubscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

When I check profiler, I can see that in both of these scenarios EF adds _id suffix and tries to query for nonexisting customer_id column in addition to customerID. I have tried to explicitly map foreign key for derived types, but EF was then complaining about:

> The foreign key component 'CustomerID' is not a declared property on type 'TVSubscription'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

CustomerID has no place in derived class, but even when I tried moving it there it did not work (I suspect because EF was then trying to map with another inheritance strategy).

Now, I understand that I can go with something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TVSubscription> TvSubscriptions
{
    get { return Subscriptions.OfType<TVSubscription>(); }
}
```

However, with this approach EF queries db for the whole set of subscriptions, and then filters it locally to return only TVSubscriptions. This is certainly not ideal as Customer can have hundreds of subscriptions and preferably I would want EF to query and return only subscriptions of certain type - as it already does when I use dbContext.

So the question is, how can I include list of TVSubscriptions in Customer class and have EF query for only those?

If this is not possible, can someone explain what kind of assumptions EF is making when I add collection of derived classes to Customer entity.